# How to fit the text inputs in div using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form using Bootstrap and the text input widths are too long. I tried to set the `width = 35%` of class `form-control` in bootstrap.css and it looks ok, but when I resized the screen it overlapped the other `<div>`. As of now I changed it back to 100%. And it is too long and it overlap the other `<div>`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">    
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h4>LOGIN</h4>
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: solid 2px black">
                <div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 456px">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <form role="form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>REGISTER</h4>
                                        <p>Please login to take advantage of promotions and benefits reserved to registered users.</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 35px">
                                        <h5>EMAIL ADDRESS* </h5>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h5>PASSWORD* </h5>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <span><input type="checkbox" style="margin-top: 20px" /></span><span>&nbsp;Remember me next time</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <span>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='register.html'" >REGISTER NOW</button>
                                        </span>
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl2" data-featherlight-variant="fixwidth">Forgot your password?</a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                </form>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h5>&nbsp;</h5>
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: solid 2px black">
                <div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 456px">
                    <h5>NEW USER</h5>
                    <div class="register-notify">

                        <p>Register now and enjoy the benefits of My Account. Only registered users can:</p>
                        <p>- Access to your personal information through My Account</p>
                        <p>- Use the Wish List to save their favorite products</p>
                        <p>- Complete the checkout process more quickly</p>

                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-top: 150px">
                        <input type="button" value="REGISTER NOW"  class="register-button" onclick="location.href='register.html'" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the class of the `div` tag to `col-sm-6`. This should do the trick.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6"> <!--The div tag before the form-->
        <form role="form">
```

Check out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XMnqR/).